# Asp.net WebApi deserializes UTC time string to local time

Tags: asp.net-web-api, json.net, utc

I have this url

http://example.com/api/record/getall?startdate=1994-11-05T17:15:30Z

and this webapi endpoint

```
[ActionName("GetAll")]
public object GetAll(DateTime startDate)
{
     ...
}
```

The problem I face is that the startDate received the deserialized string as a local time, "**11/5/1994 9:15:30 AM**" instead of stay in UTC time which what I wanted "**11/5/1994 5:15:30 PM**".

I'm using VS2012 update2, latest Json.net nuget package.  However, if I use json.net in a separate console app to test, the same string "**1994-11-05T17:15:30Z**" is able to deserialize correctly into "**11/5/1994 5:15:30 PM**".

Anyone know what is wrong here?

Comment: Can't you get UTC time from deserialized date?

Comment: Found a solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12246254/asp-net-web-api-modelbinders

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Although you have already [found a solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15007363/10263) for your question, I thought I would take a shot at explaining why it did not work as you expected.

WebApi uses content type negotiation to determine what parser to use when reading data.  That means it will look at the `Content-Type` header of the request to make the determination.  If the `Content-Type` header is set to `application/json` then it will use Json.Net to parse to content and feed it to your method.

An HTTP GET request, such as the one you are making here, does not have a content type set.  The "content" in this case is really just the query string from the URL.  WebApi does not expect to find JSON data here, so it is not going to try to use a JSON parser to make sense of it.  Even if it did, the string you are passing to your GetAll method isn't even valid JSON.  (It would need to be quoted to be valid.)

Now, if you were to change your method to accept a POST request, and you set the content type header to `application/json` and passed the date as a JSON string in the body, then WebApi will use Json.Net to parse it, and it will work like you expect.

For example, say your method looked like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public object GetAll([FromBody]DateTime startDate)
{
    try
    {
        return new
        {
            StartDate = startDate.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"),
            StartDateKind = startDate.Kind.ToString(),
        };
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        return ex.Message;
    }
}
```

And you made a request like this (note the POST):

```
POST http://localhost:57524/api/values/GetAll HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Length: 22
Host: localhost:57524

"1994-11-05T17:15:30Z"
```

The response would look like this:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: no-cache
Pragma: no-cache
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Expires: -1
Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.0
X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Fri, 31 May 2013 01:25:48 GMT
Content-Length: 57

{"StartDate":"1994-11-05 17:15:30","StartDateKind":"Utc"}
```

As you can see, it does correctly recognize the date to be UTC in this scenario.

Comment: I really appreciate your taking the time to explain. +1 and marked you as answer.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with GET request with [FromUri] attribute attached to your request param. Not sure how to get it working.

Comment: I know this is a bit old post but did anyone found a solution for [FromUri] attribute when parsing dates ?

Comment: Yeah although this explains why this is happening I'd like to know how to solve this without resorting to manual date conversion inside the controllers.

Answer (score 6):

If you want to modify the way Asp WebApi parses uri parameters of your GET requests, you can write custom `IModelBinder` like this:

```
public class UtcDateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var stringValue = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName)?.RawValue as string;
        DateTime parsedDate;
        if (!DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, null, DateTimeStyles.AdjustToUniversal, out parsedDate))
        {
            return false;
        }

        bindingContext.Model = parsedDate;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And then override default binder:

```
GlobalConfiguration.Configure(configuration => configuration.BindParameter(typeof(DateTime), new UtcDateTimeModelBinder()););
```

[Parameter Binding in ASP.NET Web API](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/formats-and-model-binding/parameter-binding-in-aspnet-web-api)

Comment: If your date is already formatted in ISO format "1994-11-05T17:15:30Z". then the DateTime.TryParse should be modified as DateTime.TryParse(stringValue, null, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out parsedDate)

Answer (score 0):

Just use [`DateTimeOffset`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetimeoffset?view=net-5.0) instead of `DateTime` as the input type for your API:

```
[ActionName("GetAll")]
public object GetAll(DateTimeOffset startDate)
{
     ...
}
```

Pass the date in the querystring as UTC e.g.

```
startDate=2021-10-01T12:00:00.000Z
```

This will create a C# `DateTimeOffset` and its`UtcDateTime` property will have the UTC `DateTime`.

(The `LocalDateTime` property of the `DateTimeOffset` will also be the UTC `DateTime`, and the `Offset` property of the `DateTimeOffset` will be a `TimeSpan` of `00:00:00`. This is different to a `DateTime`, which instead has its `Kind` property set to `Utc` for a UTC DateTime)

Using `DateTimeOffset` also has the advantage of allowing the date to be passed as a local time e.g. the following date can be passed to the API:

```
startDate=2021-10-01T18:00:00.000+05:00
```

Note that when passing this in the querystring, the `+` must be URL encoded as `%2B`:

```
startDate=2021-10-01T18:00:00.000%2B05:00
```

This will convert to a `DateTimeOffset` representing the local time in a timezone 5 hours ahead of UTC:

```
startDate.DateTime = {1/10/21 6:00:00 pm}
startDate.UtcDateTime = {1/10/21 1:00:00 pm}
startDate.LocalDateTime = {1/10/21 1:00:00 pm}
startDate.Offset = {05:00:00}
```