# Date model binding in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, asp.net-core, .net-core

I'm building one ASP.NET Core Web API and I've recently found one issue regarding the binding of DateTime values.

In truth I have one `minimumDate` and one `maximumDate` properties for filtering in a certain resource. These are part of one `Filtering` object which just gets populated on the controller by model binding.

The issue is that the request is sent like this:

```
minimumDate=2014-01-20T00:00:00.000Z&maximumDate=2014-03-21T00:00:00.000Z
```

and on the controller one gets when debuging:

```
MinimumDate = 19/01/2014 22:00:00
MaximumDate = 20/03/2014 21:00:00
```

This is clearly wrong. The expected was:

```
MinimumDate = 20/01/2014 00:00:00
MaximumDate = 21/03/2014 00:00:00
```

It is reducing one day in both the minimum and maximum dates and furthermore it is messing the time part.

I thought at first it had to do with culture and globalization, but this is already set in the Startup configure method as:

```
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("pt-BR");
```

so I doubt this to be the reason.

What am I doing wrong? How to get dates properly being sent to the API with model binding?

**EDIT** I managed to solve the issue by manualy parsing the datetime objects using:

```
filtering.MinimumDate = DateTime.Parse(this.Request.Query["minimumDate"], null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
filtering.MaximumDate = DateTime.Parse(this.Request.Query["maximumDate"], null, System.Globalization.DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind);
```

In other words, bypassing the model binder. Still, I want to know: why model binding is presenting this strange behavior here?

Comment: This SO https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16826093/asp-net-webapi-deserializes-utc-time-string-to-local-time has a longer explanation why it behaves this way and that JSON.net is not involved here. Another answer in the same post provides a solution for asp.net (not core!) using a custom IModelBinder. I am sure there is a similar possibility in asp.net core.

Answer (score 4):

To me it looks like the model binder which uses Json.net behind the scenes is converting your UTC time to local time for BRT (UTC-3) which is why you see the date and time change. You should be able to update your JsonSerializerSettings property as:

```
new JsonSerializerSettings
{
     .....
   DateTimeZoneHandling = DateTimeZoneHandling.Utc,
    .....
}
```

That should take care of proper model binding in your case.

Comment: This does work when the date is bound FromBody which is JSON. But not when the query string is bound, as in the question.